# receiving and sending data from arduino to stml476RG

Tags: c, arduino, arm, stm32, usart

I am looking to receive serial data from an arduino, and then transmit the data received back to the arduino, however I am having trouble receiving the correct data. Below is my code, I am not sure on where I have gone wrong, can anyone see any problems? 
I am using register level programming and using USART 3 on the STM32L476RG development board, an I am using ADM485 chip to transfer the data between each serial port.

```
#include "stm32L476XX.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int T ;
int R ;
uint8_t z;

void USART3_init(void)
{

   USART3->BRR   |= 26UL<<4;  //BAUD RATE MANTISSA 234UL<<4
   USART3->BRR   |= 1UL<<0;   // BAUD RATE FRACTION 6UL<<0  
   USART3->CR1   |= 1UL<<0;  //enable USART
   USART3->CR1      ^= 0UL<<28; //1 start bit, 8 data bits, n stop bit
   USART3->CR1   ^= 0UL<<12; //also sets word length to 8 data bits
    USART3->CR1     ^= 0UL<<10; //no parity control
    USART3->CR1   |= 1UL<<6;   //Transmission complete interrupt enabled
   USART3->CR1      |= 1UL<<7;   //TXE interrupt enable
    USART3->CR1   |= 1UL<<5;   //RXNEIE interrupt enable    
    USART3->CR2   ^=00UL<<12;    //1 stop bit
    USART3->CR1     |= 1UL<<3;   // enable transmitter
    USART3->CR1   |= 1UL<<2;  // enable receiver

      NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn); //enable USART interrupts 

}


void Delay(void)
{
        uint32_t i=0;
        for (i=0; i<50000; i++){}
}


void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
 //Delay();

    if ((USART3->ISR>>5)&1UL) //Check if RXNE interrupt is high
{ 
  z = USART3->RDR; //put what is on RDR into Z (also clears RXNE flag)
    GPIOB->ODR    |= 1UL<<5; //set transceiver into transmit mode       USART3->TDR = z; // Clears TXIE flag and outputs z on TX

 }

 if ((USART3->ISR>>7)&1UL) //Check if TXIE interrupt is high
 {

GPIOB->ODR    &= 0UL<<5; //sets transceiver in receive mode

 } 

 if  ((USART3->ISR>>6)&1UL) //Check if TC interrupt is high
 {  
    USART3->ICR   |= 1UL<<6; //Clear TC flag
  GPIOB->ODR    &= 0UL<<5;  //Set transceiver in receive mode    
 } 

}

void RCC_GPIO_init(void)
 {
RCC->APB1ENR1 |= 1UL<<18; //Enable USART 3 clock
    RCC->AHB2ENR    |= 1UL<<1; //Enable GPIOB clock

  GPIOB->MODER   =  0; //reset all register bits
  GPIOB->MODER  |= 2UL<<20; //enable GPIOB pin 10 as alternate function
  GPIOB->MODER  |= 2UL<<22; //enable GPIOB pin 11 as alternate function
  GPIOB->MODER  |= 1UL<<10; //enable GPIOB pin 5 as output

  GPIOB->AFR[1]  =  0;   //reset all register bits
  GPIOB->AFR[1] |= 7UL<<8; //enable GPIOB pin 10 as TX
  GPIOB->AFR[1] |= 7UL<<12; //enable GPIOB pin 10 as RX

  GPIOB->ODR    ^= 0UL<<5;  //GPIOB pin 5 as low (to put ADM485 transceiver in receive mode)
}


int main (void)
{

   RCC_GPIO_init();
 USART3_init();
while(1)
        {                       
    }       

}
```

Comment: What makes you think it is a software problem in the first place? Have you measured the signals?

Comment: Yes, I have a logic analyser connected to the tx and rx pins of both the arduino and stm32, and the arduino/adm485 chip is supplying the correct data to the rx pin of the stm board, however using keils debugger and a logic analyser connected to the tx pin, the board is reading the data in as an incorrect value and outputting this incorrect value

Comment: Does the ST board have a RS485 transceiver too? It's a bit unusual for these kind of hobbyist boards. Because if you take one RS485 line and plug it to a UART, it may or may not work, depending on which differential line you happened to pick.

Comment: @user10451545 is the baud rate correct?  Is the bit width of the output 'incorrect' data exactly the same as the bit width of the incoming 'correct' data?

Comment: @Lundin 'RS485'...... ah.....

Comment: Yes, my current configuration is that I have a arduino Uno board connected to an adm485 IC (rx and tx), this is then connected to another adm485 IC using beldin 8723 cable, the rx and tx pins of that are then connected to the corresponding tx and rx pins of my USART on the STM board

Comment: @MartinJames could you help me with setting the baud rate please? I think I have set it correctly, I can either use pclk or sysclk, the sysclk is 80Mhz, so I then calculated my baud rate using an equation in the stm32 reference manual, in the code I provided I am using the automatic baud rate detector

Comment: @Lundin I have just disconnected the adm485 chips and connected the tx, rx pins of the arduinos directly to eachother and it worked perfectly, can you offer advice as to why it is the adm485 chip, because if I replace the stm32 board with an arduino it works no problem with the adm485 chips

Comment: Do not use magic numbers and shifts. It is not simple AVR. Who has the time to check everything with the RM. Use human readable decinitions

Comment: I think what you should do next is to post at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. That site has an easy to use schematic editor. If you could draw a simple schematic how the transceivers are connected to the MCUs and each other, someone will find the problem in no time. Otherwise, the usual culprits with any UART: mixing up tx and rx pins, missing signal ground.

Comment: @P__J__ sorry bro I learnt this way at uni, an i use this way as i learn more than just using the standard peripheral libraries, but to make it more readable i have added comments describing the magic numbers and why they are used, i have worked out correct baud rate and the whole system is now working! However i only want it to transmit data when it has received a full byte on RX, because at the moment it is transmitting on TX as soon as it receives on RX, could you help with this please?

Comment: @Lundin thankyou for your help, after you told me to look up the transceiver, i figured out because the STM32 was working in full duplex and the RS485 is half duplex, it was pretty much overloading the lines with data, i have now got it to only transmit off TX after it receives on RX, however i want it to transmit on TX when it has received the full byte on RX, can you offer any advice with this? I am trying to avoid delays as it locks up the processor which is bad practise for the long run i have heard

Comment: @user10451545 very bad uni. if you change it to do now waste my time I can help you

Comment: @P__J__ okay, what style should i change it to? what do u say is best, i am still learning so any advice you give me is appreciated, what is better practise style of coding for this task?

Comment: @user10451545 You have to specify a protocol. One side should receive a full protocol, and when that is sent, both nodes switch direction ("ping pong"), a pure software solution. Some more cumbersome solutions involve handshaking with RTS/CTS, but that would mean additional transceiver circuits and I see no point of using it here.

Comment: @Lundin okay I think I have the right idea then i just need to implement it better in my STM code, currently i have one arduino master, an arduino slave and an stm slave, so the master sends an address, the corresponding slave with that address sends back that address plus the status of a push button connected to it, then the master sends the next address, i had it working fine with 1 arduino master and 2 arduino slaves, i am just now trying to implement it with an stm board instead

Comment: Use definitions from the CMSIS

Comment: @P__J__ oh yes i see what you mean, we have learnt that way at university too but i thought i would learn more doing register level, would you suggest i always use CMSIS over register level?

Comment: CMSIS are mostly only human readable definitions. It is not a high level library. It is not HAL or SPL!!!! Your uni teaches strange stuff.

Comment: You use it anyway because USART3 is a CMSIS define which uses the CMSIS typedef.

Comment: @P__J__ i put it down more towards me not paying proper attention at university haha, but thank you for your explanation, i will now use CMSIS over register level so it is more readable, i have managed to alter my code so everything is working now, thanks everyone who helped :)

Comment: @user10451545 Universities teach the microcontroller architectures, for example they show you the registers and the concept that writing to certain bits in certain registers may have an effect in hardware peripherals. That doesn't necessarily mean that you should be using magic numbers in your code, neither that this is a common practice.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok ahh yes this will be where I getting mixed up, I will use CMSIS from now on, thanks guys